# Need a simple explanation of a left-right shift register

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, shift-register

I'm familiar with basic shift registers. I'm having a hard time understanding the one below. I feel like I'm overthinking it due its complicated appearance. Would it be possible to direct me to a way of approaching in a way that makes it easier to understand?

[image]

Comment: Each set of three 3-inputs AND gates + 3-inputs OR gate is a multiplexer with 2 selection bits, C0 & C1, and 3 inputs : Left data, right data, parallel load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start by redrawing the diagram, slightly:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbg2Yv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The upper four 3-in AND gates are for gating \$D_0\$ through \$D_3\$ to the 4-bit register. You can easily see that \$C_0=1\$ and \$C_1=1\$ in order to enable these four 3-in AND gates.

The middle four 3-in AND gates are for gating \$Q_1\$ through \$Q_3\$ as \$D_0\$ through \$D_2\$, respectively, and the **shift right input** as \$D_3\$ to the 4-bit register. You can easily see that \$C_0=0\$ and \$C_1=1\$ in order to enable these four 3-in AND gates.

The bottom four 3-in AND gates are for gating \$Q_0\$ through \$Q_2\$ as \$D_1\$ through \$D_3\$, respectively, and the **shift left input** as \$D_0\$ to the 4-bit register. You can easily see that \$C_0=1\$ and \$C_1=0\$ in order to enable these four 3-in AND gates.

Finally, it's easy to see that the **CLK** is blocked when \$C_0=0\$ and \$C_1=0\$. So there will be no changes to the 4-bit register in that case.

The four 3-in OR gates simply OR all three of the different groups of four bits. Only one of those three will have been enabled (allowed to have any output other than **0**) by the selection based on \$C_0\$ and \$C_1\$. So there's no problem there. They simply pass along whichever value is active at the time to the 4-bit register inputs. If the clock is permitted, then the selected 4-bit value is then latched.

Hopefully, that helps a little. It's not much of a change. I mostly just re-organized a little bit.